# как загрузить value в input_е своим значением

Tags: javascript, html

заблудился в 2-х соснах: почему `value` в `input` не грузится? Внутри функции `value` обновляется, а при выходе из функции в поле `value` пусто. Не пойму в чем ошибка.

```js
var my_vid_name;
$('body').click(function(event) {
  if ((event.target).className == "kino") {
    my_vid_name = (event.target).text;
    document.getElementById("vid_name").value = my_vid_name;
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="vid_name" type="text" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var my_vid_name;
$('body').click(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).hasClass("kino")) {
    my_vid_name = $(event.target).text();
    document.getElementById("vid_name").value = my_vid_name;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="vid_name" type="text" value="" />
<div class="kino">Bloodsport</div>
<div class="kino">My Fair Lady</div>
```